# Beautifulsoup - Scraping from a specific class that contains h4

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image: please see the picture of codes of the website]

there is a lot of <div class=event-sub-lists but I want the one with h4 that contains 2021. that's all I want. but I couldn't create a if clause or smt else. how can I do that, can you explain? thanks in advance!!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
import requests

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.``3945.88 Safari/537.37"
url = "https://www.fpri.org/events/archive/"
data = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": user_agent})
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")

document = Document()

events = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "events-sub-list")
for event in events:
    event_name = event.find("li")
    link = event.find("a")
    try:
        print(event_name.text)
        document.add_paragraph(event_name.text, style='List Bullet')
        print(link['href'])
        document.add_paragraph(link['href'])
    except:
        continue

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get correct response from server, set `User-Agent` HTTP header:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.fpri.org/events/archive/"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

for li in soup.select('h4:-soup-contains("2021") + ul li'):
    print(li.text)
```

Prints:

```
Haiti, Cuba, and the History of U.S. Involvement in the Caribbean  - Barbara Fick - July 29, 2021 -  Events  
Tug-of-War in the Black Sea: Defending NATO’s Eastern Flank  - Maia Otarashvili - July 15, 2021 -  Events  
Freedom of the Border  - Ronald J. Granieri - July 13, 2021 -  People, Politics, and Prose  
The Future of U.S.-China Proxy War  - Aaron Stein - July 6, 2021 -  Events  
The “Polypandemic” Threat: Impacts on Development, Fragility, and Conflict  - Nikolas K. Gvosdev - June 29, 2021 -  Events  
Difficult Choices: Taiwan’s Quest for Security and the Good Life—a book talk with Richard Bush  - Jacques deLisle - June 24, 2021 -  Events  
Why Africa Matters: The Official Launch of FPRI’s Africa Program  - Charles A. Ray - June 17, 2021 -  Events  
We Shall Be Masters: Russian Pivots to East Asia from Peter the Great to Putin  - Ronald J. Granieri - June 15, 2021 -  People, Politics, and Prose  


...and so on.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the text within each tag by using `tag.text` i.e

```py
div = soup.find_all("div", class="events-sub-list")
h4 =[p for p in div if "2021" in p.text]
```

or more comprehensive (note, you do not get only the `h4` from the specific div as I'm your example this way)

```py
h4= soup.find_all("h4")
h4 =[p for p in h4 if "2021" in p.text]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! but when i write that, it says " h4 =[p for p in div if "2021" in p.text]
NameError: name 'div' is not defined @CutePoison

Comment: you can get the `h4` directly (see editted answer)

Answer (score 1):

Try now:

```
div = soup.find_all("div", class_ ="events-sub-list").h4
get_2021 =[p.text for p in div if "2021" in p]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! when i write that, it says div is not defined. i change 'div' with 'events,' and then it still does not give me only 2021. it gives the first elements of each "events-sub-lists." https://codeshare.io/Pd4Xme

Comment: i don't understand what i am doing wrong :(